# Outputting inset plot (aka 'plot in plot') to pdf using ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting two plots inside each other following this [guide](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/ggplot2-plot-inside-a-plot/) using my own datasets [user_interactions.csv](http://codeshare.io/nOMdP) and [weeks.csv](http://codeshare.io/GYJkj). However, I cannot output the combined plot properly. I've tried both using `ggsave()` and `pdf()`. The latter messes with the placement and generally makes the plot uglier. On the other hand `ggsave()` only outputs the last plot. How can I use `ggsave` to output this combined inset plot?

**Code**

```
rm(list=ls())
work_dir <- ".../figures/R"
setwd(work_dir)
dat_weeks <- as.data.frame(read.csv("weeks.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE))
dat_int <- as.data.frame(read.csv("user_interactions.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE))

label_font_theme <- theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16),
                          axis.text.x= element_text(size=14),
                          axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, vjust=1.5),
                          axis.text.y= element_text(size=14))      

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
main_p <- ggplot(dat_weeks, aes(x=week, y=acc)) + geom_line(aes(linetype=type), size=1) 

main_p <- main_p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,13,1), name='weeks of data')
main_p <- main_p + scale_y_continuous(name='user classification accuracy')
main_p <- main_p + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 13), ylim = c(0.5,0.75))
main_p <- main_p + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
main_p <- main_p + scale_linetype_manual(name="",breaks=c("HourNet","QuarterNet"), values=c(3,1))
main_p <- main_p + label_font_theme

sub_p <- ggplot(dat_int, aes(x=interactions, y=accurate)) + stat_smooth(lty=1, method = "loess", size=1, colour=c("#000000"))
sub_p <- sub_p + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 2000), ylim = c(0.5,0.75))
sub_p <- sub_p + scale_y_continuous(name='user classification accuracy')
sub_p <- sub_p + label_font_theme

vp <- viewport(width = 0.5, height = 0.5, x = 0.8,
               y = unit(3, "lines"), just = c("right","bottom"))

theme_white <- function() {
  theme_update(panel.background = element_blank(),
               panel.grid.major = element_blank())
}

full <- function() {
  theme_white()
  print(main_p)
  theme_set(theme_bw())
  theme_white()
  print(sub_p, vp = vp)
  theme_set(theme_bw())
}

full()
ggsave("acc_weeks_ggsave.pdf")
```

**Edit:**

This is the output from using `pdf()`. It is not like the original plot as it for instance has some weird white boundaries for the subplot.

```
pdf(file="acc_weeks_standard.pdf",width=8,height=6)
full()
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: How can this work? `ggsave` is not even specifying a plot in this command.

Comment: My default it uses the last plot. I've tried selecting the plots, but I don't know how to select both of them at once.

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/ggsave.html

Comment: try with `annotation_custom`

Comment: Can you post what it it is supposed to look like too? It looks fine to me...

Comment: I think I don't understand your problem so I deleted my answer.